# Help some material or advise with rotary switch

Tags: microcontroller, c

I have 16 position rotary swith and netX microconntroller. Can someone hepl me give me example how to read position of a rotary swith.

Comment: Switches aren't programmed, they're turned by hand. But regardless, tie the common to ground and activate internal pullups.

Comment: how can i read position of a rotary switch

Comment: Try searching with Google!

Comment: 1) Could you read 16 separate switches? 2) read Ignacio's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to start with the model of the switch and it's datasheet. chances are it will output various BCD codes on a group of pins (4?) which your microcontroller will need to evaluate to determine the switch position. eg 0001 = position 1, 0011 = position 3 and so on.

Comment: If it's 16 positions it's unlikely to be BCD, just binary.

Comment: It may also simply be a SP16T switch with one common and 16 selectable terminals. In this case, you can have different value resistors on each pole, connected to a common resistor to make a changeable voltage divider, fed into an ADC. Otherwise, you'll need 16 GPIO pins as inputs.

Comment: Good point re BCD.